# Kill Jupyter Notebooks from within the notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am looking for a way to automatically kill the notebooks kernel to free up the memory after finish running some cells.

Is there a magic command that I can use from within the notebook cells to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exit()`; the kernel will restart automatically but all the resources of the old kernel will be cleaned.